# flask jinja macros variable in url_for

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a flask app with a jinja macro that looks like that

```
{% macro icon(site, title="") %}
    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename="icons/XXX.png") }}" alt="{{ title }}" class="img-icon">
{% endmacro %}
```

What I need to do is have the filename equals to the `site` variable passed to the macro. so instead of the XXX it should have the value of `site`.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

```
{% macro icon(site, title="") %}
    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='icons/%s.png' % site) }}" alt="{{ title }}" class="img-icon">
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: Thank you! It is working, but for some reason, the value of site is being preceded by a ton of spaces. the url is looking like `icons/      google.png` rather than `icons/google.png`, `site` is of course stripped. any idea why?

Comment: not sure about jinja and flask, but it is [recommended](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) to use `'icons/{}.png'.format(site)` instead of `'icons/%s.png' % site` in python :)

Comment: @deathApril You should make a separate answer, because it is more correct than the older % style.

Answer (score 6):

Recommended way of string formatting in python ever since 2.6 ([pep-3101](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/)) is to use [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
{% macro icon(site, title="") %}
    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='icons/{0}.png'.format(site)) }}" alt="{{ title }}" class="img-icon">
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: and for Python 3.6+, f-strings are also available: `f'icons/{site}.png'`